# How can I change the default `src` directory for Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I want to include Gatsby into an existing codebase that already uses `src` as the source directory for the application's code.

I wanted to create a subdirectory named `gatsby` inside my project and install all the dependencies in the root's `package.json` file. This would allow me to build a static site using Markdown + React to showcase components with their supporting documentation, replacing Storybook in my project.

The directory structure is thus:

```
<root>
 |- gatsby
 | |- components
 | |- layouts
 | \- pages
 |- src [my application's source code]
 |- node_modules
 |- package.json
 \- gatsby-config.js
```

Is there a way to tell `gatsby` to use the `gatsby` directory instead of `src`? I've tried configuring the paths using `gatsby-plugin-filesystem`, but this didn't work for me:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Example'
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'src',
        path: `${__dirname}/gatsby`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'pages',
        path: `${__dirname}/gatsby/pages`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'layouts',
        path: `${__dirname}/gatsby/layouts`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'components',
        path: `${__dirname}/gatsby/components`
      }
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    'gatsby-plugin-preact',
    'gatsby-transformer-remark'
  ]
};
```

I get this error when running `gatsby develop`:

```
error There was an error compiling the html.js component for the development server.

See our docs page on debugging HTML builds for help <link>


 Error: Module build failed: TypeError: fileSystem.statSync is not a function

 - exists.js:7 module.exports   [project]/[babel-loader]/lib/utils/exists.js:7:25

- resolve-rc.js:13 find   [project]/[babel-loader]/lib/resolve-rc.js:13:9

- index.js:113 Object.module.exports   [project]/[babel-loader]/lib/index.js:113:132
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is open [issue 2424](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2424). It appears that until this issue is completed not much can be done. you can follow along [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2918)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// gatsby-config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/gatsby/pages`,
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

See [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-page-creator/#how-to-use) for more details